# Copy and paste excel to sql server table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel

Using Excel 2010 and SQL Server 2008 R2.

I used import and export data (32 bit) wizard to copy data from excel spreadsheet to SQL Server.
Why I got an error?

By the way, copy and paste doesn't work for excel 2010. It will paste all the data in one field. And import and export wizard 64-bit doesn't work as well. It has not excel option in the Data Source dropdown menu at all.

Thanks.

[image: error]

Comment: If your Excel is 2010 why are you putting 2007 in the Excel Version?

Comment: There is no 2010 there, I had to select 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are unable to successfully install the driver for the Jet engine you can use CSV (Flat Text file import) with very similar features.

Comment: When I select database, it doesn't remind me the table name. And what is the destination database? Native client 10.0 or Microsoft OLEDB Provider SQL SERVER?

Comment: I would use OLEDB Provider for SQL Server 2008, not sure what you mean by 'remind me the table name'?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to import xlsx file(latest version that is not supported by Jet Oledb drivers), so download the appropriate version on basis of your OS 32/64 bit. These drivers are freeware from Microsoft.

[Download drivers for Excel 2007 on your machine](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)

Comment: I installed AccessDatabaseEngine_x64.exe, but import and export 64-bit still doesn't have excel item in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Excel 2007 and 2010 file types are grouped together as Microsoft Excel 2007.